# Empty subdatasets when reading hdf5 in python

Tags: python, hdf5

I am trying to read a hdf5 image in python (it's my first time). In hdfview I see the `subdatasets` with no problem, but in Python, I can't read them. When I do:

```
f = gdal.Open(fileName, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
sub = f.GetSubDatasets()[0][0]
```

It gives:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  sub=f.GetSubDatasets()[0][0]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Any idea of why does it happen?

Comment: Have you tried h5py?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it with h5py, in case it helps anyone, here is it:

```
f=h5py.File(fileName, "r") # Opens the file in reading mode
datasetNames=[n for n in f.keys()] # identifies the datasets included in the image
# for n in datasetNames: print(n) # print the names of the different datasets
lat=f['LATITUDE'] # LATITUDE is a dataset in my file
lat_at=lat.attrs['SCALING_FACTOR'] # SCALING_FACTOR is an attribut of the dataset LATITUDE
```